# Phonegap app working locally, not working on phone

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I have written a phonegap application, and it performs a pretty simple task, it gets some JSON from a YQL link, and then displays it nicely to the user. This works excellently when I run it using Google Chrome on a Desktop, but, my client tells me that it does not work on his device which is Android 2.3. What can be going wrong? I'm using phonegap build to build to app, and they tell me that it is given internet permission, but, when my client puts the APK on the phone (its not on the market yet), does he need to do something special for it to access the internet?

Thanks a lot,

Dhaivat

Comment: Two questions, are you using SSL and is the web service using a self signed cert?

Answer (score 1):

in phonegap, allow external host : Open phonegap.plist -> external host and add your url or * to allow all

Answer (score 0):

within the phonegap app the webapp runs under the file:// protocol - this might affect things.

you should test this at least on an emulator yourself - clients usually screw up anything some might screw up when testing ;) best would be to test on an actual device tho.

Comment: It doesn't work on the emulator either, I'm trying to figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help but I had a similar problem testing my app here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17496104/json-wordpress-feed-not-appearing-in-android-studio-emulator-using-phonegap

I needed to change access origin to ="*"/ in my config.xml